# if no me captura los datos correctos

Tags: php

Hola amigos es que tengo una duda, estoy trayendo una tabla de oracle, en esta hay unas notas de un estudiante,  tengo un while que recorre todo e imprime en una tabla en html dichos datos pero dentro de ese while tambien estoy haciendo otra cosa y es guardando los datos en un arreglo, pero quiero que dicho arreglo solo guarde los datos de un valor en especifico ejemplo en este caso quiero que tome todos los datos que son mayores a (4), y me agarra algunos pero no todos y no entiendo por que
**Tabla**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**codigo:**

```
 <table id="">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Cod Materia</th>
                    <th>Notas</th>
                    <th>Periodo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $i = 1;
                while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
                    if (oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL') > 4) {
                        $notas[] = oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL');
                    }
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo oci_result($stid, 'MATE_CODIGOMATERIA'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo oci_result($stid, 'PEUN_ID'); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php

                }
                var_dump($notas);
                oci_free_statement($stid);
                oci_close($conn);

                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**el codigo donde estoy haciendo es aquì:**

```
 $i = 1;
                while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
                    if (oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL') > 4) {
                        $notas[] = oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL');
                    }
```

Si se dan cuenta en el array me pone esto:
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpvTi.png)=> string(1) "5" }
es verdad que 5 es mayor que 4, pero tambien otros numeros como 4,41 es mayor que 4 y no se guarda

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de llamar a la columna con la información la tienes declarada como `REAC_NOTAFINAL` pero en tu tabla se llama `nota`, por eso no encuentra la información a comparar y la considera como false. Tienes que poner la columna de tu DB de la siguiente manera

```
while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
   if (oci_result($stid, 'NOTA') > 4) {
   $notas[] = oci_result($stid, 'NOTA');
}
```

Asi tomarias el valor de la nota que esta almacenado en tu DB.
Puedes consultar la documentacion de la funcion [oci_result](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-result.php)

Comment: Hola, gracias pero la verdad no entendi, en este if en la parte donde esta REAC_NOTAFINAL es por que ese campo se llama asì en la DB no entendi por que pusiste NOTA, dices que en mi tabla se llama NOTA pero no tengo ningun campo llamado NOTA

Comment: Me confundi con la tabla que agregastes a tu pregunta, pense que era la tabla que usabas en tu consulta, error mio, pero lo que puedes haces es filtrar la informacion directamente de la base dedatos usando un where REAC_NOTAFINAL > 4, asi te ahorrarias el ciclo en php